# OpenCV Random Forest Tie Breaking

Tags: c++, opencv, random-forest

Can somebody tell me if the OpenCV random forest code resolves ties (i.e. there is no clear majority vote) by random selection or if there is a more deterministic mechanism? I can't seem to find an answer in the OpenCV forums, the O'Reilly OpenCV book, or Google.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper into the OpenCV code (), I found the following relevant code:

```
if( nclasses > 0 ) //classification {

  int max_nvotes = 0;
  cv::AutoBuffer<int> _votes(nclasses);
  int* votes = _votes;
  memset( votes, 0, sizeof(*votes)*nclasses );
  for( k = 0; k < ntrees; k++ ) {
    CvDTreeNode* predicted_node = trees[k]->predict( sample, missing );
    int nvotes;
    int class_idx = predicted_node->class_idx;
    CV_Assert( 0 <= class_idx && class_idx < nclasses );

    nvotes = ++votes[class_idx];
    if( nvotes > max_nvotes ) {
      max_nvotes = nvotes;
      result = predicted_node->value;
    }
  }
}
```

So, what it appears to do is:

1. Run through each tree and get the prediction
2. Update the vote count for that particular prediction class
3. Compare the vote count for that particular prediction class with the max vote count (max_nvotes)
4. Update max vote count where necessary

So, the idea of randomly breaking ties is not directly integrated into this piece of the code but one should keep in mind that the trees within the random forest ensemble are generated randomly. Thus, in theory, the tie breaking process is random since the order of the trees (and the order of their predictions) is random. One additional thing to note is that a tie goes to the first class to get the maximum number of votes.

Also, if it's the majority vote that counts, then one could short-circuit the for-loop if any one of the classes exceeds more than half the number of trees. So, if there are 50 trees and any one of the classes has more then 25 votes then there is no need to go through and obtain predictions from the remaining trees (since they will be irrelevant for changing the majority vote).